# Yaml Runtime Configuration for Phoenix Framework

Tags: configuration, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm playing around with Elixir *(and Phoenix in specific)* and had a question that I couldn't find in the documentation.

I come from the Java world where a standard practice is to create a Jar, and have a config file (Yaml/TOML/JSON) which is read at web-application startup to load configs. That way, the "compiled" JAR can remain constant while only the config changes between deployment environments.

eg. `cat /mnt/appconfig.yaml` might show

```
local-dev:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2

development:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2

staging:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2

production:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

and if I run my app with `realm=production java -jar myapp.jar`, then it picks up the values from the `production` block and those values can be held in a static class and used anywhere in the app. The KVs are things like URLs to access for different services in different realms, some random flags etc.

I was wondering what is the Elixir-way of doing the same?

Comment: You should learn about releases. Also check out [`Config`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html).

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/deployment.html

Comment: Hey @AdamMillerchip , Thanks for the reply. Yes I've already checked out the links you mentioned. However, it looks like all of those are compile time solutions rather than runtime configurations. Is there something specific that I'm missing there?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Beam releases are analogous to JVM jar files. You can specify a `runtime_config_path` which the release will use, and place the config file in that location (at compile time).

From the `mix release` [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Release.html#module-application-configuration):

> ### Application configuration
>
> Releases provides two mechanisms for configuring OTP applications: build-time and runtime.
>
> #### Build-time configuration
>
> Whenever you invoke a `mix` command, Mix loads the configuration in `config/config.exs`, if said file exists.
> It is common for the `config/config.exs` file itself to import other
> configuration based on the current `MIX_ENV`, such as
> `config/dev.exs`, `config/test.exs`, and `config/prod.exs`. We say
> that this configuration is a build-time configuration as it is
> evaluated whenever you compile your code or whenever you assemble the
> release.
>
> In other words, if your configuration does something like:
>
> ```
> config :my_app, :secret_key, System.fetch_env!("MY_APP_SECRET_KEY")
> ```
>
> The `:secret_key` key under
> `:my_app` will be computed on the host machine, whenever the release
> is built. Setting the `MY_APP_SECRET_KEY` right before starting your
> release will have no effect.
>
> Luckily, releases also provide runtime
> configuration, which we will see next.
>
> #### Runtime configuration
>
> To enable runtime configuration in your release, all you need to do is to create a file named
> `config/runtime.exs`:
>
> ```
> import Config
> config :my_app, :secret_key, System.fetch_env!("MY_APP_SECRET_KEY")
> ```
>
> This file will be executed
> whenever your Mix project or your release starts. Your
> `config/runtime.exs` file needs to follow three important rules:
>
> - It MUST `import Config` at the top instead of the deprecated `use Mix.Config`
> - It MUST NOT import any other configuration file via
>   `import_config`
> - It MUST NOT access `Mix` in any way, as `Mix` is a
>   build tool and
>   it is not available inside releases
>
> If a `config/runtime.exs` exists, it will be copied to your release and executed early in the
> boot process, when only Elixir and Erlang's main applications have
> been started. Once the configuration is loaded, the Erlang system will
> be restarted (within the same Operating System process) and the new
> configuration will take place.
>
> You can change the path to the runtime
> configuration file by setting `:runtime_config_path` inside each
> release configuration. This path is resolved at build time as the
> given configuration file is always copied to inside the release:
> `releases: [ demo: [ runtime_config_path: ... ]]`